# What is the most state-of-the-art, pure python, XML parser available?

Tags: python, xml, google-app-engine, jython

Considering that I want to write python code that would run on Google App Engine and also inside jython, C-extensions are not an option. Amara was a nice library, but due to its C-extensions, I can't use it for either of these platforms.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[ElementTree](http://effbot.org/zone/element-index.htm) is very nice. It's also part of [2.5](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html).

Comment: @coonj ... indeed. ElementTree should be available in AppEngine and jython 2.5, but jython 2.2 is still recommended for production use (jython 2.5rc4 is out so it shouldn't be that much longer).

Comment: @Blauohr Awesome! As I said, with rc4 out it shouldn't be that much longer.

Answer (score 4):

There's also [Beautiful Soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) (which may be geared more toward HTML, but it also does XML).

Comment: One problem I've run into with Beautiful Soup's XML parsing is that [it doesn't know about self-closing tags](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/documentation.html#Parsing%20XML).

Answer (score 1):

[xml.sax](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.sax.html) is a builtin SAX parser

Answer (score 1):

I would normally recommend lxml, but since that uses a C-library (libxml) the alternative would have to be, as Aaron has already suggested, ElementTree (as far as I know there is both a pure python and a c implementation of it available).
[Found this via google search](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=18)

Good luck!